# Drag 2 borderless form at the same time

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, mouseevent

I have read lot of comments here on Stack and around the internet about how to move a borderless form in .net

The solutions I came across are two.
1) use the winapi functions
2) handle the mousedown/move/up events.

I already implemented the move form with the winapi calls, but in my project, just below the main form there is a second one, (log form, which records events about what the user and the program itself do).
This log form is implemented as a sliding menu, if the user clicks a particular button, the log form will slide down and appear just at the bottom middle of the main form.

I have tried in both ways but i wasn't able to implement a routine such that if the log form is open, whenever i drag the main form, the log form must follow attached.

What i tried:
(for sake of semplicity I omitted some flags about checking if the log form is shown or not etc.. I just want to understand why i can't move the log form).
dlls imports and const declaration are correct.

```
private void headerPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {   
    //this is the event in the mainForm.cs, which handles the mainForm drag, header panel is a little panel on top of the borderless mainForm
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0); 


            //using the logger form handle, and issue the same command doesn't work
            SendMessage(Log.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
```

i tried also the mouseDown/Up/Move events, with mouseDown/Up setting a flag and the mouse move doing

```
private void headerPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    if(isDown)
    {
        log.Position = new Point(//X, Y values here)
    }
}
```

With this solution the logPanel updates it's position only when i releas the mouse button, i tried putting log.Refresh()/Invalidate() because i was thinking there was not enough time to redraw all the form, but it didn't work, and also using an awful thread.sleep(10) to allow it to redraw didn't work.

Any clue what should I do? or am I doing something really wrong here?

Comment: That is indeed the expected outcome with this code, mouse moves are now used to move the window and no longer raise the MouseMove event.  Wrong approach, use the LocationChanged event instead.

Comment: `private void MainForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isLogOpen)
            {
                logger.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 250, this.Location.Y + 500);
            }
        }`

did the trick! thanks!